# InkScape svg file to show geometry path data

Tags: svg, inkscape

Using [InkScape](https://inkscape.org/) (latest version 1.0.1) on my `Windows-10`, I created the following `svg` file that I thought would also show the geometry data Path attribute value (as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65728684/1232087)). But it is not showing data attribute similar to `<path d="M507.712 311.74c-7.903......../>`. **Question**: How can we either convert the following `svg` file to a file similar to the one shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65728684/1232087), or using `InkScape` is it possible to create `svg` file similar to the file shown in the above link?

Another thing I noticed that this file shows nothing when opening in `Google Chrome`, `Microsoft Edge`, or `FireFox`. It was supposed to show the text `TEX` (similar to the one shown in the above link).

**My svg file created from InkScape**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   width="210mm"
   height="297mm"
   viewBox="0 0 210 297"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg16">
  <defs
     id="defs10" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata13">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     id="layer1">
    <text
       xml:space="preserve"
       style="font-weight:bold;font-size:10.5833px;line-height:1.25;font-family:sans-serif;-inkscape-font-specification:'sans-serif Bold';fill:#ffffff;stroke-width:0.264583"
       x="68.791664"
       y="99.029755"
       id="text20"><tspan
         id="tspan18"
         x="68.791664"
         y="99.029755"
         style="fill:#ffffff;stroke-width:0.264583"
         rotate="0 0 0"
         dy="0 2.96 -2.96">TEX</tspan></text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: You've created some text in white which is difficult to see on a white background. Inkscape has text to path conversion if you want to convert text to paths but that's not a programming question and would be off topic here.

Comment: @RobertLongson The background is blue, and it shows fine on `InkScape` with blue background and text in white.

Comment: I see nothing in the markup you've provided that would set a blue background.

Answer (score 0):

Select the text. Do Path > Object to Path.